# select query and limit for each of IN id's

Tags: mysql

I've got `contacts` table that has id|city_id|category_id|email fields.
The basic query is

```
SELECT id
     , email
  FROM contacts 
 WHERE city_id IN (".implode(',', $arrCity).") 
   AND category_id IN (".implode(',', $arrCategory).")
```

But I need to set a limit: 10 rows for each category in the city. Is it possible?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is tricky.  In MySQL the easiest way is to use variables:

```
SELECT id, email
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             (@rn := IF(@cc = CONCAT_WS(':', city_id, category_id), @rn + 1,
                        IF(@cc := CONCAT_WS(':', city_id, category_id), 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM (SELECT c.*
            FROM contacts c
            WHERE city_id IN (".implode(',', $arrCity).") AND 
                  category_id IN (".implode(',', $arrCategory).")
            ORDER BY city_id, category_id
           ) c CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @cc := '', @rn := 0) params
     ) c
WHERE rn <= 10;
```

This enumerates the rows within each city/category combination.  The outer `WHERE` limits it to 10 in each combination.

Comment: And now I have error `Unknown column 'city_id' in 'field list'` at the `(@rn := IF(@cc = CONCAT_WS(':', city_id, category_id), @rn + 1` line and  that is weird

Comment: @Fiter . . . `city_id` is in your original query.

Comment: I have replace `FROM (SELECT c.*` to `FROM (SELECT *`  and that works! Thank you!

Comment: Hello! I need to upgrade that query but it's too complicated for me ( Selected rows must have unique contacts.catalog_id value